# Python for loop with numerical list not working as expected

Tags: python

I am trying to print a list, delete item 0 and then print the list again for all items in the list. This is very simple but it's not working as I expected.It stops short of completing the for loop for all of the list items.

I tried using the range function inside a list first with both the del and pop() methods. That did not work so I have been using a list and get the same results.

```
seals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for seal in seals:
    print(seals)
    seals.pop(0)

Expected Result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9]
[9]

Actual Result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: You're modifying a list as you're iterating over it.  Don't do that.  All kinds of weird things can happen, as you saw.

Comment: for seal in seals: print(seals);seals=seals[1:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is funny here, so you have to be very clear to him :D :

```
seals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for seal in seals[:]:
    print(seals)
    seals.pop(0)
```

Or use `range`:

```
seals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for seal in range(len(seals)):
    print(seals)
    seals.pop(0)
```

Both reproduce:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9]
[9]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to `pop` values off until there are no more, it's probably clearer to write that intention into the code with something like:

```
seals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

while seals:
    print(seals)
    seals.pop(0)
```

This avoids the problem of modifying the list while iterating the same list.

If you don't want to modify seals as you go, then you could do something like:

```
seals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i, v in enumerate(seals):
    print(seals[i:])
```

`seals` remains unaltered at the end of this.

Comment: That's definitely more satisfying @U9-Forward. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, your welcome and it good that it is better code now :-)

Comment: @mackie Please accept one of the answers if they work, either mine or Mark's, and once you have 15 reputation please up-vote the two answers of me and Mark.